# How can send emails to a group of people on multiple selected rows in a google sheet at the same time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I made a script on Google Apps script in a google sheet document that sends email to an individual when I select a row in a google sheet. It reads all email and name information from the selected row and combines with a template to send email. It works perfectly. However, when I select multiple rows or cells, it just sends the last selected row. How can I send emails to multiple selection on rows at the same time? I am a new learner to Google Apps Script and learned a lot from this website. So if you can help to figure it out, I would be very appreciated. Below is my code. Thank you so much in advance.

```
function sendEmail() {
  // define a couple constants for the function
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var lsh = ss.getSheetByName('List');
  var tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var subject = tsh.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var n = lsh.getLastRow();
  var dt = new Date ();

  // Make sure the selected row has text
  if(lsh.getActiveCell().isBlank()) {
    ui.alert("Please select a row with interviewer");
    return;
  }

  // if valid, get the correct row of data.
    var row = lsh.getActiveCell().getRow();

  // get the range for that row
    var rowRange = lsh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 5).getValues();

  // Build the object to use in MailApp
    var nameint = rowRange[0][0];
    var lastname = rowRange[0][1];
    var email = rowRange[0][2];
    var nameauthor = rowRange[0][3];
    var book = rowRange[0][4];

    var msg = "Interviewer: " + nameint + " " + lastname +  "\nEmail: " + email + "\nAuthor: " + nameauthor + "\nBook Title: " + book + "\n Successfully Sent!"

  // Here for illustration only
    
     ui.alert(msg, ui.ButtonSet.OK)

    // MailApp.sendEmail(address, subj, body);
    
      var email = rowRange[0][2];
      var firstName = rowRange[0][0];
      var authorName = rowRange[0][3];
      var bookTitle = rowRange[0][4];
      var message = tsh.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
      const sent = "Sent"
      message = message.replace("<firstName>", firstName).replace("<authorName>", authorName).replace("<bookTitle>", bookTitle);
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
      lsh.getRange(row,6).setValue(dt);
      lsh.getRange(row,7).setValue("Sent");
    
    // set the send status in col 6 7
    
}
```

Comment: Select muliple rows or cells and use a rangelist to loop through each of them

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cooper again. I know I'm getting too much. I am actually stuck with it again. Can you help me figure out regarding the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgl = sh.getActiveRangeList();
  const rga = rgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation()).flat();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rga));
}

Execution log
11:18:19 AM Notice  Execution started
11:18:17 AM Info    ["A1","B2","C3","D4","E5","F6","G7","H8","I9","J10"]
11:18:21 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Cooper. It worked and I learned a lot from you during the process. Finally, I have completed my first script project. Thank you very much for your help.